# How to implement admob native express ad in recyclerview using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, admob, firebaseui, native-ads

I wanna know that to implement admob native express ad in recyclerview using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, please give the answer in detail if you're able to, thanks in advance

Comment: I got nothing,I want help

Comment: you are supposed to show what you have done first.  People are not expected to do the work for you

Comment: http://developine.com/integrate-firebase-advance-native-admob-ads-android-kotlin-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in your viewholder class:

```
public NativeExpressAdView nativeAdview;

public YourViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);

    nativeAdview = (NativeExpressAdView) view.findViewById(R.id.nativeAdView);
}

public void loadNativeAd(AdRequest nativeRequest){
    if(nativeAdview != null) {
        nativeAdview.loadAd(nativeRequest);
        nativeAdview.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                nativeAdview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

then load from adapter:

```
protected void populateViewHolder(YourViewHolder viewHolder, myModel model, int position) {

       //Native Ads
        viewHolder.loadNativeAd(nativeRequest);
```